# Stunning after slaughter

Tags: slaughter-shochet-shecht

I just read an article that basically said that the law in Canada is such that, it is detrimental in producing a normal output of kosher meat for their market.

Canada apparently needs one to make sure that the animal is dead for good after shechita and this takes time on the production floor. This apparently had other undesirable domino effects.

My questions is, why don't we slaughter al-pi-halacha and then later stun the animal?
This way, the Jews are happy and the Canadian goyyim are happy.

https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/386920

Comment: If we stunned after shechita, we could be seen as implicitly agreeing that shechita does not end the (sentient) life of the animal - which could be a problem is other jurisdictions.